# Include Google experiment code in template header for specific pages

Tags: javascript, php

I need to add Google Experiments code in two pages for an A/B testing.
The code has to be inside the `header` section of the template, otherwise it won't work.

This is what I've tried on my template:

```
<?php
$titulo=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 10);

if($titulo=='/experience'){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src=".../exp.js"></script>';
}

?>
```

The `if` statement is working OK, it is including the `exp.js` script only to the pages I want.

This is exp.js

```
<!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var
k='15950497-1',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
if(l.search.indexOf('utm_expid='+k)>0)return;
function f(n){if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.
indexOf(';',i);return escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c.
length:j))}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;d.write(
'<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':
'://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?'+'utmxkey='+k+
'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date().
valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})();
</script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>
<!-- End of Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
```

This is returning the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

On line 2 of `exp.js`

I've also tried to echo the script directly on the template but it creates a syntax error with the quotes (I tried both simple and double).

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: on thing is you have 3 dots instead of 2 in `../exp.js` not sure thats your problem

Comment: @Victory this is just an example, on my real code I have the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **echo** to:

```
print file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/../exp.js');
```

Comment: It is working, the only thing is I have the string: 812 on top of the pages,